# gdal image quality problem when using gdalbuildvrt?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt

I have ~1000 1GB images that I want to make into a COG w/ JPEG compression.  Any time I try to use gdalbuildvrt to create a vrt of my entire directory of images then I get big quality loss.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Left image is a sample of how I'd like to make my entire directory of images into a single COG.  This VRT has only 2 images, N00-E000_ur and N00-E000_ul.

> gdalbuildvrt test.vrt *.tif

> gdal_translate test.vrt testjpg90vrt.tif -of COG -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co QUALITY=90

Right image is just a comparison of making a COG from just 1 of the images:

> gdal_translate N00-E000_ur.tif N00-E000_ur_cog_jpeg.tif -of COG -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co QUALITY=90

[image: Left image is 2 images in a .vrt, Right image is just 1 image]

Comment: Does the image look similar if you open them with QGIS? Now you seem to use GeoServer and the intergrated viewer.

Comment: Yes the imagery looks the same in QGIS.

Comment: Could you share some test data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use

```
gdalbuildvrt -resolution highest
```